# How to know which apt repository is slow?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I run `sudo apt update` and it took like 30 minutes and not even done, how to know which repository that are slow?

```
Get:88 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com jammy/main amd64 Packages [119 kB]
Get:89 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com jammy/main i386 Packages [51.9 kB]
Get:90 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable/main amd64 Packages [7,737 B]
Get:91 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.10/prod kinetic/main amd64 Packages [30.0 kB]
Get:92 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.10/prod kinetic/main arm64 Packages [3,273 B]
Get:93 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.10/prod kinetic/main armhf Packages [989 B]
Ign:94 https://dl.modular.com/public/installer/deb/pop jammy/main amd64 Packages
Get:95 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main arm64 Packages [15.9 kB]
Get:96 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main armhf Packages [15.9 kB]
Get:97 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main amd64 Packages [15.9 kB]
Ign:78 https://mirror.repository.id/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:83 https://dl.thorium.rocks/debian stable InRelease
Get:94 https://dl.modular.com/public/installer/deb/pop jammy/main amd64 Packages [2,265 B]
Ign:98 https://dl.thorium.rocks/debian stable Release
Ign:78 https://mirror.repository.id/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:98 https://dl.thorium.rocks/debian stable Release
<-- stuck like forever
```

I don't know which one that stuck, from ps aux | grep apt also didn't show which repository that causing the stuck

```
/usr/lib/apt/methods/https
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http
```

Comment: How many sources do you have on your system? And what is the system? Why are you looking for amd64 _and_ arm64 _and_ i386 _and_ armhf_ packages?

Answer (score 5):

The `apt` utility has several debugging options, which are listed in [`man apt.conf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/apt.conf.5.html#debug%20options).

A useful debug parameter for `sudo apt update` is the `Debug::pkgAcquire` option, as stated here:

> ```
> Debug::pkgAcquire
>     Log when items are added to or removed from the global download queue.
> ```

To invoke this option, run:

```
sudo apt -oDebug::pkgAcquire=1 update
```

There is an even more verbose option named `Debug::pkgAcquire::Worker`, which logs all interactions.

> ```
> Debug::pkgAcquire::Worker
>     Log all interactions with the sub-processes that actually perform downloads.
> ```

Similarly, this can be run with:

```
sudo apt -oDebug::pkgAcquire::Worker=1 update
```

Hopefully, these debug options will allow you to see where the `apt update` process is stalling.